# How to dumpdata from table outside of django project

Tags: django, django-models

To create a fixture for an app in my project I can do:

```
$ manage.py dumpdata app > app.json
```

How would I do the same for the `auth` app, from the django core? That is, I want to transfer all my data from any table starting with `app_`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't matter that it's not inside project folder:

```
$ manage.py dumpdata auth > auth.json
```